# Objective-C: why a custom object will be a zombie

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, parameter-passing, nszombie

I'm developing an app in Objective-C using ARC.

My simplified code looks like this:

***ClassA (.m)***

```
MyCustomClass *obj = [[MyCustomClass alloc] initWithValue1:@"abc" value2:1000];
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithObject:obj];
// "vc" will become the first item of a UITabBarController
```

***MyViewController (.h)***

```
- (id)initWithObject:(MyCustomClass *)obj {
    ...
    localReferenceToOjbect = obj;
    ...
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // do something with "localRefernceToObject" <---
}
```

launching the app will result in a call to a zombie: when the ViewController is shown, the "obj" will be already deallocated and so i can't use it anymore.

**my workaround is:**

***ClassA (.h)***

```
@interface ClassA : UIViewController {
    MyCustomClass *obj;
}
```

***ClassA (.m)***

```
obj = [[MyCustomClass alloc] initWithValue1:@"abc" value2:1000];
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithObject:obj];
// "vc" will become the first item of a UITabBarController
```

is this the right way?! i don't think so: why i've to store an istance of an object that is useless for *ClassA*?
i can't get an explanation on what's actually happening. could you help me?

Comment: I don't see a difference in the two examples of `ClassA.m` you show?

Comment: If you've created getters/setters, try `self.localReferencesToObject = obj;`

Comment: make sure localReferenceToObject is declared as a strong property in the MyViewControllerClass

Comment: @trojanfoe the difference is that in the second ClassA the "obj" var is declared as a property of ClassA itself.

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer "localReferenceToObject" is not declared as "property (nonatomic, strong) ..." but simply like in ClassA.h example (i don't know how to call that way)

Comment: @mynameis You can follow as what AliSoftware said, but instead of declaring it in your interface, you can declare it in your `.m` instead with a category.

Comment: Just to be precise, a class extension is a bit different as a category. The syntax is very similar, and a class extension has the same syntax as a category with no name, but a class extension is the official way to declare private properties and methods, and more importantly everything declared in a class extension is needed to be implemented in the implementation. This ensure that the compiler will warn you in case you forget to implement something, whereas it will silent the error if you use a real category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in the fact that it is not logical to keep around a  reference to obj in ClassA.

But if you need to keep around the reference to obj for MyViewController to use it, retain it in MyViewController, not in ClassA, because that's MyViewController that will use it.

The easiest way to do this is to transform your `localReferenceToObject` you use in `MyViewController` into a `@property(retain) propertyToObject;` (or `@property(strong) propertyToObject` if you use ARC) and access it in your `MyViewController.m` with `self.propertyToObject` (instead of `localReferenceToObject`, to be sure to call the property's setter and thus really retain the object).

This way, the object will be retained and kept around while your `MyViewController` instance is still alive.

---

*[EDIT]* If you want this property to be private, you can declare it in the class extension so that it is not accessible from other classes, as in the below example. See [here in Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2) for more details.

#### In your MyViewController.h header file

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
// Here you write the public API in the .h / public header
// If you don't want your property to be visible, don't declare it there
@end
```

#### In your MyViewController.m file

```
@interface MyViewController ()
// This is the private API, only visible inside the MyViewController.m file and not from other classes
// Note the "()" to declare the class extension, as explained in Apple doc
@property(nonatomic, retain) MyCustomClass* referenceToObject; // Note: use strong (which is a synonym of retain) if you use ARC
@end

@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize referenceToObject = _referenceToObject; // not even needed with modern ObjC and latest LLVM compiler

- (id)initWithObject:(MyCustomClass *)obj
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        ...
        self.referenceToOjbect = obj;
        ...
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // do something with "self.refernceToObject"
}

// This memory management code is only needed if you don't use ARC
-(void)dealloc
{
    self.referenceToObject = nil; // release memory
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Personally, as suggested by Apple in some WWDC sessions, I now really rarely use instance variables and prefer the use of properties instead, either public in the .h or private in the .m.

---

*If you use ARC, you can still use an instance variable instead of a property as ARC will retain it for you, but as long as you make sure your instance variable is declared as `strong` and not `weak`.*

Comment: i've got the last sentece and now i'm going to try it in my actually code.
but the first one is not clear to me. as far as i know, the @property tag let the property be visible (and maybe editable) by the object who has created it (in my example i can do something like this in ClassA.m "vc.localReferenceToOjbect = obj").
and i don't want to let the object be editable nor visible to others.

Comment: No the idea that a `@property` is visible and accessible is not true. You can declare the `@property` in the class extension in your .m file (instead of in the primary `@interface` in your .h file) so that it is not visible to other classes, as explained [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2) in Apple's documentation. I edited my answer to give you an example how to do this.

Comment: i guess this IS the answer and i really appreciate your example and explanation. now i'm reading (and studying) the links you've mentioned because i feel that something was not clear to me.
next i will try to real code and - i hope - accept your answer :-)